# M+% replacing value AND also a kill to end of line (C+k)

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'd like to search and replace, say `::` and then replace all instances with a single `:` and a `C+k`

I had tried `M+%` then `::` and lastly `:C+qC+k` but it just gave me `^K`actually displaying in text and didn't kill the line.

Thoughts?

EDIT #1:
Just for completeness sake, the data looks like this:

`here:: stuf i dont want

more:: oth crud

etc:: I am wicked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it hard to understand what you're actually trying to do, but that's probably just me.

**1)** If what you have is the following:

```
foo
:: bar
baz
```

and what you want is this:

```
foo
:
baz
```

then you can use regular expression search/replace like this: <kbd>M-C-% : : . * RET : RET</kbd>. This calls the function `query-replace-regexp` to which you pass double colon followed by `.*` to match the rest of the line. You replace whatever matches with a single colon.

(Note that <kbd>M-C-%</kbd> might not work if you run Emacs in the console (`-nw`) since not all terminals can produce the required escape sequence. In that case, simply type <kbd>M-x query-replace-regexp</kbd> instead.)

**2)** If what you have is the following:

```
foo
::
bar
```

and what you want is this:

```
foo
:bar
```

then you simply need to include the carriage return in your search pattern: <kbd>M-% : : C-q C-j RET : RET</kbd>. Note that this does not require regexp search, normal string search is fine for this purpose.

**3)** If what you have is the following:

```
foo
:: bar
baz
```

and what you want is this:

```
foo
:baz
```

then you can combine the two techniques above and do: <kbd>M-C-% : : . * C-q C-j RET : RET</kbd>. Here, we include the carriage return in our regular expression search pattern.

Comment: #1 is what i wanted. i am taking my rails schema and making fixtures out of it, so replacing `t.integer "string", :default => "mama"` and i want that second `"` after the word string to be blank and kill everything after itself. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Create a keyboard macro where you first I-search for `::`, remove the last `:` and then hit `C-k`. Execute that keyboard macro as long as it matches. This is how I would do it :-)